# MySql adding column name with last_insert_id()

Tags: mysql, addition

I'm trying to add a new mysql column in a table, using an insert_id from an insert of another table. This is the sentence that i use...

```
string sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO test (IdPico, Nombre, TextoBienvenida, FechaCreacion) VALUES (1, 'nombretest', 'aslkñdfa lsñdk asjd asldkf añlsj f', '2011-07-13 10:22:53'); ";
sqlInsert += "SET @IDTESTCREATED := CONCAT('Test', LAST_INSERT_ID(); ";
sqlInsert += "ALTER TABLE Usuarios ADD COLUMN @IDTESTCREATED BIT DEFAULT 0; ";
```

I using ASP.NET 4.0 and MySql connection, and server responds with 'Fatal error encountered during command execution. '

Could anybody help me?

Comment: If nothing else, you are missing ) at the end of the CONCAT function

Comment: This sounds like broken design; *very* broken

Comment: @wonk0 yeah, the fail is strong with this one

Comment: Sorry...this is an error transcription. In my sentence i have a ) at the end. i'm execute in mysql query browser and get error 1064...  -->You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @IDTESTCREATED := CONCAT('Test', LAST_INSERT_ID())
ALTER TABLE Usuarios ADD' at line 2

Comment: This idea makes me want to cry

Comment: I'm not sure what driver you're using, but the query function might only support a single query (such as with PHP's mysql_query) and not multiple queries separated by a semicolon. There might be a separate function for multiple queries, but I do not know ASP.NET offhand. I do, however, weep for your database and its many columns. Please, for the love of programmers who will need to maintain this monstrosity, reconsider this anti-pattern.

Comment: Sorry to all programmers. I know that is not the best way to do it.
I'm using Connector / Net 6.4.3. from MySQL's download center.

I update database with multiples query separated by ';' and run property. What I'm trying to do is add a column to a table 'users', whose name is TestXX and where XX is the value of the AutoNumber table 'Test'.

The sentence:
`code`INSERT INTO Test () VALUES (); ALTER TABLE Usuarios ADD COLUMN TestXX BIT DEFAULT 0;`code`
works property. I just want to change 'XX' for IdTest.

I have always worked with SQLServer (know SCOPE_IDENTITY ()) but not with MySql.

Answer (score 1):

Well ... I answer myself.

After making a deep search, I have not found how to add a column dynamically by a variable in mysql.

At end I had to make two querys, first to insert the test and get the id, and second to update the users table.

Since the insertion and retrieval of id are in the same query, no problems of persistent connections and concurrent updates.

```
 string sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Test (<fields>) VALUES (<values>);";
    sqlInsert += "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS IdTestInserted; ";
 string idnewtest = <result of insert query>;
 string sqlAlter = "ALTER TABLE Users ADD COLUMN Test" + idnewtest + " BIT DEFAULT 0; ";
```

I regret not having found the answer, but at least I achieved my goal.
Thank you all for your help!

Comment: I guess people are reluctant to help in something that seems so flawed. Rule of a thumb: if your relational database app needs to alter it's own tables on regular basis - something's wrong.